# Checking account transfer bank-to-bank

Tags: scams

There is this person and that got some money he put the check in his bank in Texas and his bank said that he needs to find a Countryside account to put some of that money in because they cannot take the full amount of check is a very big amount of check he wants me to open up a checking account in Minnesota so he can transfer some money into that account is he able to get any of my information like my social security number birthdate anything like that the account will be in my name but it will be a separate checking account so whatever money goes in there would be his

Comment: It's a scam. Don't do it.

Comment: **No bank has a problem depositing a large check in an account.** Of course if you just walk through the door and want to *cash* a check for $100,000, that is a different situation.

Comment: Sound like another variant of advanced-fee scam, this is just the beginning of the drama.

Answer (score 16):

> There is this person

I know where this is going.

> and that got some money he put the check in his bank in Texas and his bank said that he needs to find a Countryside account to put some of that money in because they cannot take the full amount of check

If a bank really can't deposit a large check, they'll direct him to a giant bank.

> is a very big amount of check he wants me to open up a checking account in Minnesota so he can transfer some money into

Ask yourself why he chose **you**.

Ask yourself why **he** can't find a bigger bank to handle the check.

> is he able to get any of my information like my social security number birthdate anything like that the account will be in my name but it will be a separate checking account so whatever money goes in there would be his

This has illegality written all over it.  Money laundering, most likely.

Block him in all social media and never contact him again.